# Someone who carries out medical procedures in a UI

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms, medical

I wanted to know if there is a specific hypernym for the role of someone who performs medical procedures (including, in this case, dental hygienists, dentists and dental nurses) that could be used in a limited space of a UI, sometimes without any additional context (as a role in the system, for example)?  The strings I've been provided suggest "actor", but, in my opinion, this is far too vague. Is it ok to talk about a "performer" in this context or does this bring about the idea of thespians and street music too?

Comment: I'd suggest *clinician*.  The point you make in your comment on the answer below, that this might include healthcare professionals who do not carry out 'procedures' makes the arguable argument that prescribing a medicine or speaking to a patient are not procedures.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I'm terribly sorry for providing inaccurate information. I'm not a native speaker of English and I presumed that "procedure" could be used to refer to any kind of manual (minimally) invasive non-surgical or surgical action performed on the patient's body, such as the examples I provided in my comment. I am not certain if this provides any more accurate information as I'm quite stressed out by my deadlines and probably cannot think straight, but thank you for correcting me on this as well.

Comment: In my world, "UI" means "User Interface." What does it mean in the medical world?

Comment: The text is for a user interface indeed.

Comment: @rajah9 Probably "Urinary Infection". Try not to get those two mixed up.

Comment: You don't need to be exactly precise in a user interface like this. If "practitioner" covers what you want, then don't worry if it includes other things too. You use other guidance (such as limiting the choices or providing more detailed context) to indicate what you exactly mean. A simple word that means pretty much what you want will be better than a complex word.

Comment: Funny. Make sure to wash your hands after keyboard abuse like that, @DJClayworth.

Answer (score 2):

They're called *practitioners*

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/practitioner):

> A person actively engaged in an art, discipline, or profession, especially medicine.

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/practitioner):

> a person engaged in the practice of a profession, occupation, etc.:
>  
>   *a medical practitioner*.

As far as finding a term that limits this to people who perform hands-on procedures, I don't think there is one. I don't think there are practitioners who are so specialized -- even a surgeon may sometimes prescribe medicines. However, I don't think this term is often used for pharmacists, who only deal with drugs and don't perform procedures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, the term "practitioner" seems to also include health care professionals who do not necessarily carry out procedures on the patient and may only provide consulting services or treat a disease by prescribing a medication. The word I'm looking for emphasises the nature of the practitioner as someone who has performed or will perform procedures such as fitting a dental filling, constructing a bridge/crown etc.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a more specific term like that. You might add a qualifier like "hands-on".

Comment: @ttsalo, Could you give me an example of a practitioner that does not carry out procedures on a patient?

Comment: @Barmar I think your answer is correct. I'm trying to elicit from the OP why s/he does not think "practitioner" is the correct answer.

Comment: The term I'm translating into English has the specific meaning of being a "hands-on" operation, as you said, so I guess "procedure" was a poor choice to begin with. I guess "operation" would be more accurate, but these procedures may not necessarily involve any surgery. As I'm specifically looking for a role that carries out such "operations", practitioner seems to be a bit vague. It seems the best option is to use it anyway and try to explain the role more broadly in certain places of the user interface. The problem is that a single user will not probably read all the texts of the UI.

Comment: I don't think there's a more specific term in English, maybe because most medical professionals can perform both hands-on procedures and consultation.